# voice recording in Ogg format?

Tags: java, applet, audio, voice-recording

I have created a voice recorder applet. The output sound file will be .wav format.  I want to use a compressed file format like .ogg.  I have the .ogg decoder applet and it plays the audio file through streaming.  But I need an .ogg encoder to record the voice in .ogg format.

Any samples or studies are much appreciated!

Comment: btw, for voice you may want to have a look at speex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the vorbis encoder:

http://www.xiph.org/downloads/

Comment: Even though you found the answer yourself, you should "accept" your answer so that it no longer appears as an unanswered question... just a little book-keeping. :-)