# Recording audio in OGG

Tags: java, audio

Is audio recording in the OGG format possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361162/voice-recording-in-ogg-format

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However, first, you need to decide what codec to use. `ogg` is a container format like `avi` or `mkv` or `mp4` - just knowing the container doesn't tell you everything about the format. If you want vorbis, there are some pure java encoding libraries (eg [vorbis-java](http://www.xiph.org/downloads/)) out there (not sure how polished they are!) or you can use JNI to bind one of the many C libraries. If you want some other codec, perhaps better suited to voice (speex? something else?) please specify.

Comment: @above: I am using speex currently but i am unable to play the speex files in flash. My client says he doesn't want a java applet. So confused

Comment: Yeah, you'll have better luck with mp4 (container format) + h264 (video codec) + aac (audio codec) if you need to play them in flash probably. Nothing to do with ogg though.

Comment: @above: i found a decoder for ogg-vorbis in flash thats why i want to know whether ogg-vorbis encoding is possible in java or not.

Comment: As I said, it is possible. Use the vorbis-java encoder, for example.

Comment: @above: Yeah will give it a try